# Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker on with a rails apps. This setup works on other developers machines, but not mine. I can get the mysql to "up" but not the rails app. I've been at it for 2 days now.

I'm on windows 10 home using the Docker Quickstart Terminal. I was able to run this about a year ago on the same machine.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3

ARG workdir=/bundle-api

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential netcat graphviz
RUN mkdir -p ${workdir}

WORKDIR ${workdir}

ADD Gemfile ${workdir}/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock ${workdir}/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

ADD . ${workdir}
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: bundle-mysql
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bundle_api_pwd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bundle_api_dev
      MYSQL_USER: bundle_api
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: bundle_api_pwd
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: bundle-rails
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/bundle-api:cached
      - bundle_cache:/bundle_cache
    ports:
      - "3100:3000"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: bundle_api_pwd
      BUNDLE_PATH: /bundle_cache
      GEM_HOME: /bundle_cache
      GEM_PATH: /bundle_cache

    depends_on:
      - db
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  bundle_cache:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - bundle_cache:/bundle_cache
volumes:
  db_data:
  bundle_cache:
```

To start fresh I run this:
`docker-compose build --no-cache`
Everything seems to work fine. I can see all the gems install.

Once it runs, I run: `docker-compose up` and get this error.

```
bundle-rails    | Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
bundle-rails exited with code 10
```

```
            Name                           Command                State                  Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bundle-backend_bundle_cache_1   sh                               Exit 0
bundle-mysql                    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
bundle-rails                    bundle exec rails s -p 300 ...   Exit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting `BUNDLE_PATH` in the `docker-compose.yml` but you don't set it in the `Dockerfile`. That means you gems will be installed to `/usr/local/bundle` but then when you start the container ruby looks in `/bundle-cache` for the gems.